# Is it a requirement to have an instalation of Kofax Capture on the KTM server?

Tags: installation, kofax

I am about to set up a system that has two dedicated servers for Kofax Capture and Kofax Transformation Module. I plan on using one server for Capture and the other for KTM.  Is it necessary/required to install Capture on the KTM server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, KTM requires Kofax Capture.  KTM (Kofax Transformation Modules) are implemented as a set of Kofax Capture custom modules.  These modules connect to the same KC database, KC fileshare ("CaptureSV"), and KC license server just like the built-in KC modules.  The KTM installer would not even proceed if KC was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You need to install KC and KTM on both the server Without stand alone KTM installation on the KTM server it wont work as you would also require KTM validation exe for the batches and this KTM validation exe comes along with KC i.e. MailroomVer.exe

Answer (score 0):

Kofax always recommends that a certified professional must do the installations, otherwise they wont support it. In the certification training you will find that a Kofax installation is made of a central server and its workstations. You can install KTM server in a workstation (in order to distribuite the OCR load).

Answer (score 0):

You need Kofax Capture installed in order to install KTM and have it fully operating. KTM(Kofax Transformation Modules) can be seen as an add-on which goes on Top of Kofax Capture.